# passing null values from ajax to phpscript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, null

I am having some problems with null values

Is there a good way of passing the null values from js in a way that they are interpreted the same.

This apparently is not the same

```
ajaxNullVar = null;
post_var = {'action': 'update_foto','fotoid': fotoid, 'ajaxNullVar': ajaxNullVar };
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            data: post_var,
```

in php

```
if ($_POST['ajaxNullVar']!=NULL)$ajaxNullVar='php null is not the same as a js null';
alert($ajaxNullVar);
```

I tested  for a while now, and  setting the null values in php, does not cause a problem when posting to the api, but coming from ajax it does??
Before I start thinking about a workaround, I thought I ask here first.

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't pass that parameter then i think php will read it as null. i've done the following basic test:

```
<?php
if($_GET['a'] == null){
   echo('null');
} else{
   echo('not null');
}
?>
```

Comment: but if you pass them in a function, you have to give them a value
I am now passing every variable one by one to the function, hope I find the solution fast.

Comment: I think the proaublem is with the api protocol, because the code breaks on a single variable. Now I have to check if I still have the null values issue.

Comment: Still have some evaluation problems, even with var==false. So I used a 0 instead off false in ajax.